# Novell eDirectory with .NET DirectoryServices

Tags: directoryservices, novell

In our company, we have a project which should use Novell eDirectory with .net applications.
I have tried Novell Api (http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/11204.html) to connect between .NET applications. It is working fine.

But, as per requirement, we specifically need .net API to connect not with Novell Api, which is not working. Connection and binding with .NET Api `DirectoryServices` not working.

Our Novell eDirectory is installed with following credentials:

1. IP address: 10.0.x.xx(witsxxx.companyname.com)
2. Tree : SXXXX
3. New Tree Context: WIxxxK01-NDS.OU=STATE.O=ORG
4. ADMIN Context is: ou=STATE,o=ORG
5. admin : admin
6. password: admin

I used Novell Api and used following code

```
String ldapHost ="10.0.x.xx";
String loginDN = "cn=admin,cn=WIxxxK01-NDS,OU=STATE,o=ORG";
String password = string.Empty;
String searchBase = "o=ORG";
String searchFilter = "(objectclass=*)";
Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapConnection lc = new Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapConnection();

try
{
    // connect to the server
    lc.Connect(ldapHost, LdapPort);
    // bind to the server
    lc.Bind(LdapVersion, loginDN, password);
}
```

This is binding correctly and searching can be done.

Now my issue is with when I trying to use .NET APi and to use `System.DirectoryServices`
or `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols`, it is not connecting or binding.

I can't even test the following `DirectoryEntry.Exists` method. It is going to exception.

```
string myADSPath = "LDAP://10.0.x.xx:636/OU=STATE,O=ORG";

// Determine whether the given path is correct for the DirectoryEntry.
if (DirectoryEntry.Exists(myADSPath))
{
    Console.WriteLine("The path {0} is valid",myADSPath);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The path {0} is invalid",myADSPath);
}
```

It is saying `Server is not operational` or `Local error occurred` etc. I don't know what is happening with directory path.

I tried

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://10.0.x.xx:636/O=ORG,DC=witsxxx,DC=companyname,DC=com", "cn=admin,cn=WIxxxK01-NDS,o=ORG", "admin");
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de, "&(objectClass=user)");
var test = ds.FindAll();
```

All are going to exceptions.

Could you please help me to solve this? How should be the `userDN` for `DirectoryEntry`?

I used `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection` too with `LdapDirectoryIdentifier` and `System.Net.NetworkCredential` but no result. Only same exceptions.

I appreciate your valuable time and help.

Thanks,
Binu

Comment: As far as I remember, I never got this to work properly. The [MSDN documentation on DirectoryEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx) also clearly states: *The DirectoryEntry class encapsulates a node or object in the **Active Directory Domain Services** hierarchy.* - `System.DirectoryServices` is really geared towards **Active Directory** - it doesn't really support anything else. So either keep using the native Novell API, or then you need to look into low-level, raw LDAP (`S.DS.Protocols`)

Comment: Maybe [this article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19097/eDirectory-Authentication-using-LdapConnection-and) can be used as a starting point - or [this post on social.msdn.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/netfxbcl/thread/bb145883-5f00-47f7-a7b7-1f2d09f4bf53)

Comment: I tried the following code  also with  raw LDAP (S.DS.Protocols) , but got exceptions.
try
    {
          LdapDirectoryIdentifier lid = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("10.0.x.xx",389);
          System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("cn=admin,cn=witsxxx-NDS,o=ORG", string.Empty); 
          using (System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection lconn = new System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection(lid))
                {  
                   lconn.Bind(cred);
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose your LDAP connection error, get access to the eDirectory server from the admins, and use iMonitor (serverIP:8028/nds and select Dstrace), in Dstrace clear all tabs and enable LDAP tracing, then do your bind see what happens on the LDAP side to see if there is a more descriptive error there.  Or if you even get far enough to bind and make a connection.

Comment: I really wished I understood what this answer is saying. I'm a Windows only guy, and I'm being told to connect to Novell's eDirectory to verify that the user who is currently logged in on a Windows PC is a member of Novell eDirectory group "WeAreHarris". I have no clue where to even begin.

Comment: @jp2code Then ask whomever manages the directory if they will enable LDAP tracing, and watch as you try a bind.  They may need to chose a replica to test on, that has minimal activity as it is easy to lose your test in the flood of normal events.

Comment: They are a client. We can only talk to the Sales Reps, and they are failing to get us the information we need about their network. We can't do a replica because we are a Microsoft shop, and a Novell network won't run here ...and our IT group does not have anyone who knows how to setup what a network Novell requires.